# Why do udp requests fail temporarily

Tags: networking, udp, nc

I've a UDP web server, which bound to the port 10000. I just deployed it on the server `172.20.0.10`. Then I tried to scan the port `nc -v -z -w2 -u 172.20.0.10 10000`, it seems that everyting is OK. The `nc` command shows me the output:

```
Ncat: Connected to 172.20.0.10:10000.
Ncat: UDP packet send successfully
Ncat: 1 bytes send, 0 bytes received in 2.0.1 seconds.
```

Then, I deployed it on another server `172.20.0.12`. However, I found that the `nc` command could fail temporarily. I just keep executing the command `nc -v -z -w2 -u 172.20.0.12 10000` and only about 1/10 of executions could succeed, others (9/10) would fail:

```
Ncat: Connected to 172.20.0.12:10000.
Ncat: connection refused).
```

I want to figure out why. Are there some methods or some tools that can help me?

Comment: Actually quite confused by the terminology used by NC there; is not obvious to me what a connection is in the context of UDP. Which, after all, is stateless.

Comment: @MarcusMüller At first, I found that the client can't get UDP server as exptected at `172.20.0.12`. Then I tried to use `nc`. Anyway, `nc` to `172.20.0.10` works as expected.